# RandomAccessFile seek exception

Tags: java, android, exception, sd-card, random-access

I want to seek in a file which is located on *SDCARD* (External Storage).

I opened it in read-only mode.

```
in = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
```

Everything for reading from this file stream is ok until i want to seek in file.

```
long seekPosition = 100;//sample value
in.seek(seekPosition);
```

the seek position of course is not bigger than file size and not negative.
however i face an exception whith no details.
here is exception trace:

*java.io.IOException

at java.io.RandomAccessFile.openCheck(RandomAccessFile.java:258)

at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:648)*
....

**The question is why this happens and how can i fix it?** 

Is it related to seek in file which is located on shared storage or i missed something in this process? 
My main concern is to access file bytes in random access method.

Comment: Show more code than that

Comment: I tried looking into it. `openCheck()` does throw an IOException: `Checks to see if the file is currently open. Returns silently if it is, and throws an exception if it is not.`

Comment: Is it possible that the file is closed before you call seek? Also, does your app have the "access external storage" permission?

Comment: @ethan: thanks. I got access to external storage permission. however file was closed by mistake in previous lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the (private) `RandomAccessFile.openCheck()` method (in Harvest / Android) simply checks that the file is currently open.  If it throws an `IOException`, that means you've closed the `RandomAccessFile` object.

Lesson: If you get an exception that you don't expect / don't understand:

1. Read the exception message<sup>1</sup>.
2. Look at the stack trace to see where the exception is thrown.
3. Find the source code.  (Google usually works for me ...)
4. Look at the source code to see why it is thrown.

---

<sup>1 - It doesn't help in this case, because for some bizarre reason they throw `IOException` with no message.  Its a BUG in my opinion.</sup>

Reference:

- The source code: http://opensourcejavaphp.net/java/harmony/java/io/RandomAccessFile.java.html

Comment: Thanks! i missed to remove line which close file in previous functions, so the problem is FILE WAS CLOSED!